# Max 9000 characters in Android TextView?

Tags: android, size, textview

I have items with a lot of text, mostly around 8500 to 9500 characters.
I want to display that in a scrollable textview, but when put the text in a TextView, it seems to be truncated to a max of 9000 characters, while a (the original) String object can hold more. Is there a way to extend this number? Absolutely no parameters on restricting the size of the TextView has been set.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a [link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/255026f2f05a2108?pli=1) which basically says:

> The answer is "how much memory can you allocate?"  Of course  the
>   system needs to allocate resources to measure and typeset and  render
>   all of that text.  If it's too long, consider showing the text  in
>   pages or chunks.

So if your string has 50000 characters, show it in 9000 character chunks.

Comment: Do you know whether there is a mechanism provided by Android to do this or do have app developers to implement it themselves?

Answer (score 4):

Use this on your EditText or TextView:

```
android:maxLength="1000000"
```

Some phones have an hard limit of 9000 chars by default.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking at this in 2018, I don't think there's a hard limit. I have a pretty cheap Android phone with 1 GB of RAM and was able to both edit and display over 40,000 characters of text. There is a slight initial pause when pasting into the edit box and when rendering into a text view but otherwise it works just fine.