# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (N ... N) ends beyond length 10500

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I get this exception when I call `EditText.setSelection()`

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (N ... N) ends beyond length 10500
```

N can be any number. For example if I call `setSelection(10476,10568)` N will be 10568. But `10500` is constant.

```
          java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (10568 ... 10568) ends beyond length 10500
              at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1090)
              at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:665)
              at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:658)
              at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:78)
              at android.widget.EditText.setSelection(EditText.java:91)
...
```

Are there any limitations of `EditText` that cause this?

Before I do a selection I load a text file which contains definitely more than 10500 characters as it contains ca. 12000 lines. And then I call `EditText.setText()` to put the file contents into the field. `EditText.setText()` works without any problems.
First I thought there is something wrong with the file contents, but I loaded another file and when the selection occurred I got the same exception and it contained `ends beyond length 10500`

Comment: looks like there is a limit for max TextView (EditText) length.  It is quite strange that there is one, but setting such a long text into a TextView is not a good idea definitely. Probably 10500 is your system's memory limit. check this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/JVAm8vBaIQg

Comment: @VladMatvienko What is an alternative for EdiText to accomplish it? And again setText() works. If there is a limit it would be logical to fail at that moment and not to wait till setSelection() is called.

Comment: the text might be just truncated to whatever your device can support. 10500 characters in your case.

Comment: The solution can be to split your text to smaller chunks, and use multiple TextViews in a ListView for example.

Comment: have you checked the text length after you set it to a TextView? Is it original, or 10500?

Comment: @VladMatvienko It would be great to have some reference to a documentation

Comment: I don't think that there is anything about it in documentation, as it might be **obvious thing** that you can handle only as much objects (characters?) as much memory you have. So you obviously can't set really-really long text into TextView. The only question is if 10500 is really memory limit for your system, or it is some other limit.

Comment: Some time ago I have implemented a library to handle long texts: https://github.com/metalurgus/LongTextView It does not support spannables and selsetion, and other staff like that, but you can use it as base to extend, and implement your own library.

Comment: @VladMatvienko You're right. EditText.getText().length() returned only 10500. The memory of my phone is 3GB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the actual method from `android.text.SpannableStringBuilder` where your code is failing.

```
private void checkRange(final String operation, int start, int end) {
    if (end < start) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(operation + " " +
                region(start, end) + " has end before start");
    }

    int len = length();

    if (start > len || end > len) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(operation + " " +
                region(start, end) + " ends beyond length " + len);
    }

    if (start < 0 || end < 0) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(operation + " " +
                region(start, end) + " starts before 0");
    }
}
```

It looks like your start/end is greater than the length (calculated by `length()`) in the EditText. Probably a case of truncation.

As far as number of characters an EditText can hold is not restricted from Android OS, but probably from device. See [Max 9000 characters in Android TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997078/max-9000-characters-in-android-textview) and also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/JVAm8vBaIQg

Comment: What are the rules for truncation? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Looks like there is no limit from Android OS, but probably from device. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997078/max-9000-characters-in-android-textview and also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/JVAm8vBaIQg

Comment: I would suggest to use simple webview. Use html string.

Comment: Thanks. But it may be needed to edit text in the future. I solved it with android:maxLength="1000000" from one of the links you provided. However I don't like it and consider it as a temporary solution. It would be great to put text chunks and fill only visible area of the text field. I don't know whether EditText provides some mechanism for doing this or is it delegated to the app developer.

Comment: Glad I could help. Won't web view work in your case?

Comment: I've never used it. Obviously it can highlight text and can be editable. I'll have to take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

I had such a problem when using AutoCompleteTextView. The problem is that the auto-completion window opens with a delay. If during this delay you delete the text, then when you try to open the window, the popup tries to work with the already deleted text. The only way to avoid this is to cancel opening this window. This can be done by removing all operations from the Handler of this view. 
`autoCompleteTextView.getHandler().removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);`