# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, webview

I used Faric to count my app crashes. In recent versions, I have a strange bug. Is this caused by the addition of a third-party webview? Has anyone encountered this situation, please help me, here is Some logs:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: getChars (87 ... 99) ends beyond length 90
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1018)
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.getChars(SpannableStringBuilder.java:915)
   at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:86)
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.(SpannableStringBuilder.java:64)
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.subSequence(SpannableStringBuilder.java:907)
   at org.chromium.content.browser.input.ReplicaInputConnection.setComposingRegion(Unknown Source)
   at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:349)
   at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

Comment: The problem already defined: `getChars (87 ... 99) ends beyond length 90` Check the character length on `getChars()` method.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed I can see this from the log, but I don't know how to fix it, because I don't know where the crash is in the project.

Comment: Are you using RxMarkDown library ?

Comment: Is it all the details that you are getting from fabric ?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed Not used, have you used this library before to report similar errors?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48401970/5167909

Comment: @VivekMishra I just showed the log under (#0. Crashed: main )