# Problem on putting Very long text to android Activity

Tags: android, textview

I am developing an Android app which will contain an activity with a text (+50k characters).
before I add the text this activity run normally without any problem, but after I add it and run the activity, the app closes.

Did you solved a problem like that before?

Comment: Show the log, please

Comment: Show XML, JAVA and Log Please?

Comment: **Try this** https://stackoverflow.com/a/6997185/8175701 Hope this will work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text is too long and your app crashes when it tries to display it all at once. As pointed out in this [article](https://android.jlelse.eu/best-practice-for-text-on-android-long-text-investigation-eb274acf1084):
"A solution to this is split your text into separate pieces, like paragraphs and put them all into recyclerview with different items."

Answer (score -1):

You should add your content inside a NestedScrollView to add scroll bars for long content.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
<!-- YOUR CONTENT HERE-->

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: This is not the answer, he says the app crashes, even if without NestedScrollView, it shouldn't crash. It will not scroll. But the data will be displayed.

Comment: Views inside a scroll view are all measured and laid out immediately - the same way as without a scroll view. The only thing different is that you can scroll now. The scroll view do not help in terms of performance (or saving memory).